# faq toggle div show/hide + change link text

Tags: javascript, css, toggle, show-hide

I watched/read/search many tutorials, but with no luck.
I stick with [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp).

I am trying to apply toogle acordion effect with JS (possibly CSS only) **without targeting** to divs.

There are 2 options to show content:

1. One question open / other closed
2. Each question can be open / close separatly

I don't mind, which option you choose to solve this problem.

I **can't change** any atribute to **ID elements** (e.g. id="div1", id="div2", ...)

My goal is to make something like in picture:
[image: preview]

### HTML:

```
    <div class="widget widgetFaq clearfix">

    <div class="widgetTitle"> 
        <h2>FAQ</h2> 
    </div>   

    <div class="widgetContent clearfix">   

        <div class="box boxFaq clearfix">                  

            <div class="boxTitle">
                <h3>Question one?</h3>
                <button> show </button>
            </div>

            <div class="boxContent clearfix toggle">                     
                <p>Answer to the question. Answer to the question. Answer to the question. </p>
            </div>

        </div>  

        <div class="box boxFaq clearfix">                  

            <div class="boxTitle">
                <h3>Question second?</h3>
                <button> show </button>
            </div>

            <div class="boxContent clearfix toggle">                     
                <p>Answer to the question. Answer to the question. Answer to the question. </p>
            </div>

        </div>  

    </div>   

</div>
```

### My try JS:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('button').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.toggle').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

### JsFiddle:

### [JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mikehudak/kkuyK/2/)

### SOLUTION:

( put `<button>show</button>` after `boxTitle` div )

### Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.toggle').slideToggle();

    if ($(this).text() === '+') {
        $(this).html('-');
    }
    else {
        $(this).html('+');
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().next('.toggle').slideToggle();
```